# how to post 0x31 0x01 0x00 unit8array data using fetch on android platform

Tags: android, react-native

I post unit8array data eg.[0x31, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01] using fetch, i used follow function to

```
function Utf8ArrayToStr(unit8array) {
  var out, i, len, c;

  out = "";
  len = array.length;
  i = 0;
  while(i < len) {
    c = array[i++];
    let temp = String.fromCharCode(c);
    out = out + temp;
  }
  return out;
}
```

parseint unit8array data to a string, then using fetch post it to server on ios work well. but it can not send 0x00 to serve on android;   it seems post data end with 0x00.
In this case, it can only post [0x31, 0x01] to server successfully。

how can i fixed it...

thinks